# Testing instance variable assignment in constructor (RSpec)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I would like to test simple constructor:

```
def initialize(parameters_hash)
  @parameters_hash = parameters_hash
end
```

Do you think that approach:

```
describe '.new' do
  let(:parameters_hash) { {} }
  it 'assigns input to @parameters_hash instance variable' do
    expect(subject.instance_variable_get('@parameters_hash')).to eq(parameters_hash)
  end
end
```

is proper. Maybe you know some other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

`Rspec` already implements the `assigns` helper [see here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs) for a controller that does exactly what you need.

If you need something like that for a model, consider using an `attr_reader`, and test that

`expect(subject.parameters_hash).to eq({})`